# How to get rails to process a literal file path for a static file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, static

I have an mp3 in `<my root directory>/app/assets/sound`. I want to be able to access this file from an html file, with the following:

```
<audio src="/assets/sound/mysong.mp3">
```

However the html5 audio player does not show up, and when I try to go to this link directly in my browser, I get an error:

```
Routing Error

No route matches [GET] "/assets/sound/mysong.mp3"
```

I've tried many variations on the URL, adding the `sound` directory to my `config.assets.path`, and setting `config.serve_static_assets = true` in my production.rb, and nothing is working. What is the fix for this?

Note that I don't require a high-performance server for this web page, so I don't want to handle static assets through Apache or anything else complicated. I just want a simple method for Rails to find a given file and return it.

Answer (score 0):

One easy way to fix this would be to move the file to public/sound/mysong.mp3 and reference it by src="/sound/mysong.mp3".   That should work fine, but does not use the asset pipeline.

Comment: Or just move it to `public/assets/sound/mysong.mp3`. Then he doesn't even need to change his HTML.